# How can a bank offer a higher interest rate for a savings account than for a GIC?

Tags: canada, interest-rate, savings-account, tfsa, gic

At this link on rates offered by [ICICI](http://icicibank.ca/PersonalBanking/popup_tfsa.htm), the TFSA savings account rate currently being offered is 1.8% but the GIC rate being offered is 1.75%.

But why would anyone put money in a GIC and lock it up only to get a lower rate than the savings account?

Comment: The TFSA account may change at any time and thus isn't as secured as the GIC rate you do realize, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite possibly a tactic to attract new clients..

ICICI is one of the banks with a small presence in Canada. There are also banks like Tangerine and PC Financial that are aggressively trying to get new clients to switch over from the big 5 banks.

At the time of writing, for a limited time, PC Financial is paying 2.5% interest on savings accounts versus 1.4% for a 1 year GIC.

[image]

[image]